# transforming UIImage to LandscapeRight in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, landscape-portrait, uiimageorientation

In my app, I am adding different images from the library into an array and then they are converted into the slide show. I am able to do this, but the only problem I am facing is the orientation of different images. All I want is, that when a user selects a picture from library, before inserting into the array, its orientation should be checked, and if it is other than landscape right, it should be rotated to landscape right. How can I do that? Moreover, the rotated images should be aspect fill i.e. there should be no black margins at the sides of the rotated images.

P.S. I want to rotate UIImage, not UIImageView as there are some ways available to rotate UIImageView but they don't meet my requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply rotate image like this:

```
UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: myImage.CGImage
                                                 scale: 1.0
                                           orientation: UIImageOrientationRight];
```

This should give you a pointer, than you can decide whether to rotate the image or not by comparing its size for e-g:

```
if (myImage.size.width < myImage.size.height) {
   // its portrait, do the rotation
}
```

Comment: And what is the most suitable way to rotate them?

Comment: UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: myImage.CGImage scale: 1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationRight]; as written above is very efficient way of rotating images! (simply specify which orientation you want it to rotate in the orientation: argument)

Comment: ok, the rotation works fine but there is an issue with this condition. if (myImage.size.width < myImage.size,height). No matter what orientation is, as I NSLog its height and width, I am getting same values for different orientations. How can I correct that?